# ConfigurationManager not loading settings

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

Note: I am new to `ConfigurationManager` and .NET in general.

I have:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    //...
    String path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["training_path"];    
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path) // path always null
}
```

I added...

```
Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
```

...to the top of main, and it outputs the expected default configuration file.

The configuration file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="xgboost_format.Application" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <applicationSettings>
        <myApp.Application>
            <setting name="training_path" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\test.csv</value>
            </setting>
        </myApp.Application>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

The issue is that the `path` setting is always null.  I get a `System.ArgumentNullException` when calling `new StreamReader(path)`.

How can I access the settings?

Comment: You don't have a `training_path` key in your settings; it's `path`

Comment: There isn't `appSettings`. Look at `app.config`. You have used application settings. Read @marcelN's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with (double-check the namespace is matching to whatever you have in your application):

```
String path = myApp.Application.Properties.Settings.Default.path;
```

You can also read [Using Application Settings and User Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx) which goes into more details about design-time settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="training_path" value="C:\test.csv" />
</appSettings>
```